# how to get specific index in list

Tags: python, list

I have an api and want to integrate in my flutter mobile application. I want to decode the response, and wanted to access the argument "data". so the argument "Data" has a list inside. I want to store "ABC" in string variable and want to store "123" in separate integer variable. **SO HOW I CAN ACCESS AND STORE THESE 2 DIFFERENT VALUES("ABC" and "123") IN 2 DIFFERENT VARIABLES FROM A LIST**,  I got stuck with this.

```
{
   "data":[
      [
         "ABC",
         123
      ]
   ],
   "success":true
}
```

Comment: Please don't "yell" in all caps.

Comment: `result.data[0][0]` for String `result.data[0][0]` for Int.

Comment: @Vimal you can't access a python dictionary using `dict_var.key`. You have to use `dict_var["<key>"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access a dictionary using `dict_var["<key>"]`. You can unpack a list using `var1, var2 = list_var`.

Code:

```py
theData = {
   "data": [
      [
         "ABC",
         123
      ]
   ],
   "success": True
}
str_data, int_data = theData["data"][0]
```

Comment: if this answered your question, please click the checkmark